# Insert jpg image and create pdf using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to insert jpg image on creation of pdf document, using jsPDF library. I tried to use this code:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

var niceimage = new Image();

niceimage.src = '/resources/images/myimage.jpg';

doc.text(10, 10, 'Hello world!');

doc.addImage(niceimage, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 150, 76);

doc.save('a4.pdf');
```

I get message that it is not jpg image. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that file myimage.jpg cannot be used directly in jsPDF, according to my research.
Image should be rather, converted to base64 file, and used that way in jsPDF. There is a great tool that I find for converting both jpg and png files here https://www.base64-image.de/ to base64.

Since those files are quite bulky, they will increase size of your javascript file. I find a solution for that, to put content (base64) of myimage.jpg file inside myimage.js:

```
var myImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYR..very..very....long...string...'
```

include that file inside your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myimage.js"></script>
```

Inside your main javascript file you can write:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(10, 10, 'Hello world!');

doc.addImage(myImage, 'JPEG', 10, 30, 150, 76);

doc.save('a4.pdf');
```

You will end-up with Hello world! and image underneath.

If you a new to jsPDF you can learn more at https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Hope that helps a bit ;)